# Can't dup TrueClass when precompiling ejs assets in JRuby

Tags: asset-pipeline, jrubyonrails, ejs

When running rake assets:precompile in JRuby I'm getting the following backtrace:

```
can't dup TrueClass
  (in C:/tripwire/app/assets/templates/alert_histories/index.jst.ejs.slim)
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1908:in `dup'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:249:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:249:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046:in `load'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [c:/jruby-1.7.2/bin/jruby.exe c:/jruby-1.7....]
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:249:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:249:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046:in `load'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Has anyone one else run into this?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Here are the versions of the relevant gems:

```
 ejs (1.1.1)
 rails (3.2.8)
 rake (10.0.3)
 jruby 1.7.2 (Ruby 1.9)
```